# AngularsJS $http getting data, but not showing up.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to AngularJs and stuck with $http getting data asynchronously, but not binding / showing the data.

The console.log is showing that the data is coming through alright. However, since the data is coming in asynchronously, the data is coming in after the page has already loaded.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Iterate over data from Webservice.</title>
<script
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- This is the angularjs magic. -->
<script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {

  /* Lets get some data from an actual service.  */
  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").then(
    function(response) {
     console.log("This is what came back -"
       + response.data.records);
     $scope.names = response.data.records;
    });
 });
</script>


</head>
<body>

 <h1>Get data from a webservice and show it on the page.</h1>

 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

  <ul>
   <li ng-repat="x in names">Name[{{x.Name}}]</li>
  </ul>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a mispelling `ng-repat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `ng-repat` to `ng-repeat`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {

  /* Lets get some data from an actual service.  */
  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").then(
    function(response) {
     console.log("This is what came back -"
       + response.data.records);
     $scope.names = response.data.records;
    });
      
      $scope.test = "tes1t";
      
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <h1>Get data from a webservice and show it on the page.</h1>

 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="x in names">Name[{{x.Name}}]</li> <!-Here ng-repeat ->
  </ul>
 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have invested more time on getting a good set of dev tools.

Comment: @mishtusorous what are you using now..Recommend you to use either Sublime Text or Brackets if you are working on angular

Comment: I am using Eclipse at the moment. I need something that has autocomplete.